# What does 'low-velocity' Cherenkov radiation look like?

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrinos, cherenkov-radiation

If an electron is traveling less than the speed of light, does it produce any light?  At any wavelength?

I just thought about this after reading about the attempt(s) to detect very low-energy neutrinos, like those created (allegedly) after the Big Bang?

Comment: Is the electron travelling through a vacuum? Or through a liquid like water? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that if a charge particle (like an electron) is *accelerating* then it will radiate. The heuristic reason why we should expect this is that if a charge was just moving at a constant velocity then we could perform a Lorentz boost to make it seem like the electron is not moving and the fundamental physics should be the same. However, if a charge is accelerating (say it had no initial velocity then it got a kick) the electric field far away from the charge does not know the charge started moving because information cannot travel faster than the speed of light. You can see a diagram of this process below:

[image]

This "shell" will move outwards at the speed of light and is observed as radiation.

At what frequency depends on the setup. For the above example, clearly there is no definite frequency for the above setup of a charge accelerating because the electric field is not oscillating with a definite frequency (it would instead have a large spectrum of frequencies). But one setup that does radiate at a definite frequency is an oscillating dipole (taken from Griffith's E&M). The setup is the following: if we have a dipole moment $\vec{p} = q_0 d \cos{(\omega t)} \hat{z}$ then under appropriate conditions (we measure from a large distance $r$ compared to the separation distance $d$, $d\ll c/\omega$, and $r\gg c/\omega$) then the electric field comes out to be

$$\vec{E} \propto \frac{1}{r} \cos{(\omega(t-r/c))} \hat{\theta}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle off the $z$ axis with the origin at the center of the dipole. I.e. we have a wave oscillating with frequency $\omega$, the same as the oscillation frequency of the dipole.

**Note:** Having an oscillating electric field is not synonymous with radiation. In order to be radiation, power--which you can get by integrating the Poynting vector on a sphere of radius $R$--must not go to zero for large $R$. This is important as it turns out because, for example, if our electric in the above setup went by say $1/r^2$, the power would go to zero for large $R$, thus not qualifying as radiation in the canonical sense.

Answer (score 1):

> If an electron is traveling less than the speed of light, does it produce any light? At any wavelength?

[Cerenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation)

> is electromagnetic radiation emitted when a charged particle (such as an electron) passes through a dielectric medium at a speed greater than the phase velocity (speed of propagation of a wave in a medium) of light in that medium. Special Relativity is not violated since the theory suggests that the speed of light is constant in vacuum and not in fluids due to the Refractive Index.

It can be seen in water reactors as a [light blue haze in the water about the reactor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hijBTgrvjY).

If the velocity is less than the speed of light in the medium acceleration and deceleration by interactions in the medium will produce photons/light, as explained in the answer by Tabin

It has been used in neutrino, (and other),  [detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector) by the motion of fast electrons scattered from neutrinos to detect the cosmic neutrino existence.

> I just thought about this after reading about the attempt(s) to detect very low-energy neutrinos, like those created (allegedly) after the Big Bang?

You should give a link. As far as I know, the cerenkov detectors for neutrinos are for the ones with enough energy to interact with electrons in the medium and produce cerenkov light.

Answer (score 0):

an e produces light if it is accelerated or if it travels in a medium with greater velocity than the light velocity in the medium. Slower e do not produce light when not accelerated (or braked).